# Google Cloud Service Upload Blob with Percentage

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to use Google Cloud Service to upload a video file. So far, I have this:

```
 Bucket bucket = storage.get(bucketName);
 Blob blob = bucket.create("XXXX.mp4", IOUtils.toByteArray(stream), "video/mp4", Bucket.BlobTargetOption.predefinedAcl(Storage.PredefinedAcl.PUBLIC_READ));
 System.out.println(blob.getMediaLink());
```

The code works for a video that runs for a short time, however, for longer videos, I do not know how to get the upload percentage. They have mentioned about BlobWriterOption but it only checks if MD5 or CR32C matches.

Any advice to check the upload percentage? Should I break the videos in small chunks and upload them to get the percentage or are there better options.